# Doctrine 2 - Integrity constraint violation error

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have two entities, product and affiliate. I want to insert a new product, but I am getting error:

Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'affiliateId' cannot be null

This is php code:

```
            $affiliate = $this->_em->getRepository("Common\Entity\Affiliate")->find(1);

            $product = new Product();
            $product->setAffiliate($affiliate);
            $product->statusId = $form->getValue('statusId');
            [...]
            $product->created = new \DateTime("now");

            $this->_em->persist($product);
            $this->_em->flush();
```

Product Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Common\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * A product.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $statusId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $created;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Affiliate", inversedBy="product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="affiliateId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $affiliate;

    public function setAffiliate($affiliate) { 
        $this->affiliate = $affiliate; 
    }

    /**
     * Magic getter to expose protected properties.
     *
     * @param string $property
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __get($property) {
        return $this->$property;
    }


    /**
     * Magic setter to save protected properties.
     *
     * @param string $property
     * @param mixed $value
     */
    public function __set($property, $value) {
        $this->$property = $value;
    }
}
```

Affiliate entity:

```
<?php

namespace Common\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * A product.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="affiliate")
 */
class Affiliate {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $lastModified;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $created;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="affiliate")
     */
    protected $product;



    public function getId() { 
        return $this->id; 
    }

    public function getName() { 
        return $this->name; 
    }


    /**
     * Magic getter to expose protected properties.
     *
     * @param string $property
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __get($property) {
        return $this->$property;
    }


    /**
     * Magic setter to save protected properties.
     *
     * @param string $property
     * @param mixed $value
     */
    public function __set($property, $value) {
        $this->$property = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you have setup your configuration file however I have managed to get it working with zend 1.10 framework and here it is below (just change namespace and class reference to match yours, also the code execution is at the bottom of the page)

```
<?php
namespace GR\Entity;
/**
 *
 * @Table(name="affiliate")
 * @Entity
 */
class Affiliate {

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false);
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;


    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $modified_on;

    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $created_on;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="GR\Entity\Product", mappedBy="affiliate", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $property
     */

    protected $products;
    /**
     * Magic getter to expose protected properties.
     *
     * @param string $property
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __get($property)
    {
        return $this->$property;
    }


    /**
     * Magic setter to save protected properties.
     *
     * @param string $property
     * @param mixed $value
     */
    public function __set($property, $value)
    {
        $this->$property = $value;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->created_on = new \DateTime("now");
    }
}

<?php
namespace GR\Entity;
/**
 * 
 * @Table(name="product")
 * @Entity
 */
class Product {

    /**
     *
     * @var integer $id
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer",nullable=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $status_id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime",nullable=false)
     */
    protected $created_on;

    /**
     * @var GR_Entity_Affiliate
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="GR\Entity\Affiliate")
     * @JoinColumns({
     *  @JoinColumn(name="affiliate_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     **/
    protected $affiliate;

    /**
     * Magic getter to expose protected properties.
     *
     * @param string $property
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __get($property)
    {
        return $this->$property;
    }

    /**
     * Magic setter to save protected properties.
     *
     * @param string $property
     * @param mixed $value
     */
    public function __set($property, $value)
    {
        $this->$property = $value;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->created_on = new \DateTime("now");
    }
}
```

This is an example of how to execute your code

```
$p1 = new GR\Entity\Product();
    $p1->status_id = 2;

    $p2 = new GR\Entity\Product();
    $p2->status_id = 3;

    $a = new GR\Entity\Affiliate();
    $a->name = 'test1';
    $a->modified_on = new DateTime('now');
    $a->created_on = new DateTime('now');
    $a->product = array ($p1, $p2);

    $doctrineContainer = Zend_Registry::get('doctrine');
    $em = $doctrineContainer->getEntityManager(); 
    $em->persist($a);
    $em->flush();

    $affiliate = $em->createQuery('select a from GR\Entity\Affiliate a')->execute();
    var_dump($affiliate[0]->products[0]->id);
```